# How can I make changes to Virtual Box's Info.plist on macOS Ventura?

Tags: macos, virtualization, virtualbox

I need to toggle a boolean (NSHighResolutionCapable = false) in the Info.plist for VirtualBox to allow my Windows 10 to run smooth.

Before Ventura this could be done by changing the the sharing/permissions followed by editing with any editor.

Now that I have migrated to Ventura (and installed Virtualbox 7) I am unable to edit Info.plist in /Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/Resources/VirtualBoxVM.app/Contents

What is the correct procedure to do this?

Comment: In what way are you "unable" to edit it? What happens when you try? I can edit Info.plist files of apps in BBEdit under Ventura, without changing any file permissions.

Comment: @benwiggy When I edit the Info.plist and want to write it back to disk I get "You don’t have permission to write to the folder that the file “Info.plist” is in."

And now I know the answer - I must give myself write access not to the file but to the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, many thanks to @benwiggy - give yourself read/write access to the folder in which Info.plist is found, in this case the Contents folder.

After that, you can change the Info.plist with the editor of your choice.

Comment: That's not new.  That's the way permissions have always worked.  Perhaps the permissions on the containing directory are different than they were previously.

Comment: I'd suggest using a method that doesn't alter the app's file attributes. As said, you should be able to do this using BBEdit.